# Получение уведомлений от почтового сервера

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, валидация, smtp

Передо мной стоит задача - проверять фактическое существование электронной почты. Первоначально пробовал метод SMTP verify, но узнал, что сейчас на большинстве почтовых серверов он отключен. В данный момент развернул собственный почтовый сервер mailcow. И моя проверка работает - делаю отправку пустого письма на почтовый адрес, а если его не существует - получаю соответствующее уведомление. Вопрос же мой состоит в том, как этот процесс оптимизировать - держать ради этой задачи mailcow дорого по ресурсам, да и делать проверку таким образом, думаю, не совсем целесообразно в том плане, что сначала нужно дождаться ответа на почту, потом проанализировать входящие сообщения. А можно ли как то такое уведомление получать напрямую, нужно ли разворачивать почтовый сервер для этого, если да, какой минимум нужен для этой задачи, чтобы проверка была максимально емкой по ресурсам системы и времени? Прикрутить все это мне нужно к сайту на Django, поэтому желательно решение задачи средствами python3.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Обычно просто генерируют уникальный url, шлют его на указанную пользователем почту, где просят перейти по этой ссылке для подтверждения почты. Перешёл - значит подтвердил. Соответственно, даже нет надобности иметь почтовый сервер для входящих сообщений.